# MLE discrete uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample of discrete random variable with Uniform distribution on set of integers $\{-\theta, -\theta+1, ... ..- 1, 0, 1, \theta-1, \theta\}$ where $\theta$ is positive integer. Find estimator $\theta$ by the method of maximum-likelihood.

I read that $\theta$ should be the $n^\text{th}$ order statistic? So $\theta=X_{(n)}$? Why? Can someone explain me?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Could it be that there is an absolute value in the nth order statistic?

Comment: **Hint:** The solution is certainly not the $n$-th order statistic.

Comment: @Cherryl I am sure Xi'an does know the answer (I am fairly sure everyone who responded does); but if you do as gung asks you'll see why X'an 's trying to give you a hint. JohnK gave a bigger. It will pay you dividends to think about what they're saying. [What exactly did you read? Are you sure you read it carefully? Didn't miss anything? (Did you try *sketching* the likelihood? What does that look like?)... You may like to start with a simpler problem where $Y$ is on $\{ 0,1,...,\theta\}$ (again, try drawing the likelihood); once you have that figured out this one should be simple.

Comment: @Cherryl: Suppose $n=2$ and your sample is $X_1=1$, $X_2=-1000$. Would you really guess $\Theta=X_1$? Also, the state space has $2\Theta+1$ elements.

Comment: @Cherryl: Be careful! By assumption $\Theta$ must be a positive integer.

Comment: @Cherryl: You are also confusing something. The probability of $X=x$ is $1/(2\Theta+1)$ when $-\Theta\leq x \leq \Theta$ and 0 otherwise. If $\Theta=0$, then $P(X=1)=0$

Comment: @Cherryl: What about X_2=-1000? If $\Theta=1$, what is $P(X=-1000)$?

Comment: @Cherryl: Yes that's absolutely correct. But now look at your MLE: It's $P(X_1=1)*P(X_2=-1000)=0$. So that $\Theta=1$ is not a maximum, is it? For example, is there a $\Theta$ which makes $P(X_1=1)$ and $P(X_2=-1000)$ both positive? That would certainly be a better $\Theta$.

Comment: 1. The likelihood function you gave an hour or so ago is not quite correct 2. In respect of your most recent comment --- so if the likelihood of your sample is zero when you choose $\theta=1$,  you can get a higher likelihood by *not* making $\theta=1$. What would be the likelihood if $\theta=1200$? Would it be larger than $0$? If so, can you see why $\theta$ *can't* be $1$? Where is the likelihood for $\theta$ non-zero?

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means. You need to think about which values of $\theta$ would not be ruled out by the data. It's easy to then formalize it. For example, if x1=1 and x2=-1000, $\theta=1$ is *ruled out* -- it cannot be a value that generates the data. What values of theta are NOT ruled out? Is $\theta=800$ ruled out? Is $\theta=1800$ ruled out?  For the set of values of $\theta$ which *could* have generated that data set, which one has the highest likelihood? (This is not a calculus problem!)

Comment: Try a numerical example, $x_1=1,x_2=-1000$ --- how does your idea work? How does that make any sense? 1. That minimum is always $-\theta$ -- would $-\theta$ make sense?  2. You don't observe $\theta$, so you can't use it in an estimator of $\theta$. Have you ever done any MLE calculations before? Can you do it for a continuous $U(0,\theta)$, for example?

Comment: Wow. But then why would you be playing with derivatives? You don't use derivatives for that example that you say is the only one you've seen. Okay put the book aside and try to draw the likelihood function (and then the log-likelihood if you like) for that case you just mentioned. (Was that $X\sim U[0,a]$ discrete or continuous by the way?)

Comment: 1. if the parameter is discrete, your likelihood should not be continuous. It's only defined where the parameter is. But even if the problem were continuous it's still wrong because  ... 2.You don't have any data in there. Imagine for a continuous $U[0,a]$ problem you had $x_1=1.2$ and $x_2=0.3$ ... can you see why your likelihood function would be wrong?

Comment: @AlexR. I tried to consider your hint. I need to use absolute value ? so θ^=max{|X1|,|X2|..|Xn|} or i am missing sth? Is the correct answer close ?

Comment: @ Cherryl: yep!

Comment: @JohnK  just to test my self with another example. if the Intreval is (N,N+1...N+10) then N^=min{X1,X2,...Xn} but if i had (N-10,N+10) then N^=max{|X1-10|,|X2-10|.....|Xn-10|} ? Sorry for bothering you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a similar problem with a specific data set

$X\sim U(0,\beta)$ (continuous uniform)

Let $x_1=4.31$, $x_2=1.24$, $x_3=5.15$

Note that $0<X_i<\beta$ and so in turn $0<x_i<\beta$.

Consequently, $\beta<x_i$ for any $x_i$ is not a possible value for the parameter.

As a result the likelihood function for this slightly different problem looks like this:

[image]

Now consider a discrete (integer-valued) uniform $U[0,a]$ and the observations 4, 1 and 5. Can you draw the likelihood (hint: don't draw a curve again)

Then tackle the original problem. Make sure your answer makes sense for the $x_1=1,x_2=-1000$ case Alex R mentioned in comments.

Comment: in this case β=max{x1,x2,x3}=5.15 and in mine ? in U[a,b] a=min{X1..Xn} and b=max{X1...Xn} ?

Comment: No, $\beta$ was not 5.15 (it was 6 but in practice we never know it). The MLE of it , $\hat\beta$ is 5.15

Comment: Oh yes I wrote  β instead of β^ by mistake... Actually we can't draw likelihood of integer-valued distribution. So the nth-ordered statistic is not the true answer ?.

Comment: You don't seem to have read the guidelines in the tag-wiki for [self-study questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) -- I see no genuine attempt (random guesses and no progress when errors are pointed out does not constitute genuine attempts). The guidelines ask us to give you hints, rather than complete answers, yet you're asking for what the guidelines tell us not to do . Can you do the first question under the plot in my answer now?

Comment: I understand the example above. If for example the U[-a,0] then it should be a^=min{X1,X2....Xn}. I would say average for the example x1=1,              x2=−1000.. since there is no logic  β=1. How to drow mine function ?

Comment: hmm I think i got it. I need to use absolute value ? so β^=max{|X1|,|X2|..|Xn|} ?